# Error en acentos Codeigniter Angular

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter-3

Al devolver un resultado en Codeigniter y Angular los acentos se convierten en

```
contrase\u00f1a
        ^^^^^^
```

¿Como puedo solucionar el error?

Código PHP Codeigniter

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($response));
```

Código Angular

```
$scope.ErrorMessage = data.message;
```

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
function getMessage($key){
    $file = parse_ini_file('application/messages.properties');
    return $file[$key]; 
}
```

Comment: Podrías aclarar dónde estás viendo el carácter como utf8 con el escape, y qué codificación de caracteres estás usando en CodeIgniter y PHP/Angular?

Comment: tengo el siguiente codigo: function getMessage($key){
            $file = parse_ini_file('application/messages.properties');
            return $file[$key];
        }

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a la codificación de los caracteres, si quieres poner acentos debes poner la codificación a UTF-8. Para hacer eso desde php tienes que modificar el fichero php.ini. Para hacerlo en Angular bastará con poner el meta tag html.

En esta pregunta de stackoverflow tienes un problema similar solucionado

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158043/codeigniter-config-charset-and-utf-8-support